# Basic jQuery and PHP Ajax Form Failing

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am stumped I am new to jQuery and trying to figure out what is wrong with my basic ajax attempt. Here is the form.

```
<div id="results"></div>
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="" method="post">
<p>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email"  id="email" class="sf" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" />
</p>
</form>
```

And here is the jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post('/ajax/emailadd.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#results').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The validation is working great but I can never get the Ajax post to fire according to FireBug and the PHP file just has a simple echo statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `event.preventDefault();` There is not event object anywhere so it is probably erroring out. Try checking your error console.

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
 submitHandler: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('/ajax/emailadd.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
        });
```

Note argument 'event'.